# Optimizing a double loop

Tags: c, loops, optimization, direct3d

What is the best way to optimize the following double loop on an X86 platform? 
The code is a routine to copy pixel data into a locked Direct3D texture.

I'm using a compiler that's from 2003 due to the platform I'm targeting and its restrictions.  Is a compiler that old able to match the speed I would get if I had written this code in assembly language? Or are there some tricks that can be used to speed up the C code? Maybe using `memcpy()` would be faster.

```
  int x, y;
  byte *srcdata = (byte *)compatablePixels;
  byte *dstdata = (byte *)lockedRectSubImg.pBits;

  for (y = yoffset; y < (yoffset + height); y++)
  {
     for (x = xoffset; x < (xoffset + width); x++)
     {
        dstdata[lockedRectSubImg.Pitch * y + bytes * x ] = srcdata[0];
        dstdata[lockedRectSubImg.Pitch * y + bytes * x + 1] = srcdata[1];
        dstdata[lockedRectSubImg.Pitch * y + bytes * x + 2] = srcdata[2];
        dstdata[lockedRectSubImg.Pitch * y + bytes * x + 3] = srcdata[3];

        srcdata += bytes;
     }
  }
```

Comment: _"maybe using a memcpy would be faster?"_ Well, if you're sure that the source and target data share the same memory layout, why not?

Comment: What is `bytes` - is it always equal to `4`?

Comment: A good compiler would notice that you are computing `lockedRectSubImg.Pitch * y + bytes * x` four times with the same result and replace it with one single computation; but you may want to help it.

Comment: Assuming that your 15 year old compiler can't optimise, I notice some repeated calculations in the loop. `dstdata[lockedRectSubImg.Pitch * y` and `bytes * x`. Also in the two loop ending conditions, but does `xoffset + width` change during the iteration? @AlexP commented as I was typing.

Comment: memcpy is highly optimised, so it *might* copy up to CPU's register size bytes at once instead of only single bytes, depending on data alignment matching or not. Accordingly, there are chances that memcpy *is* faster.

Comment: I have a very strong feeling that you can replace your code with something like ```for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) memcpy(dstdata + pitch * (yoffset + y) + xoffset, srcdata + y * width, width); ```.

Comment: If your ranges to copy are larger, usage of the system's DMA controller (if available/accessible) might get an interesting option.

Comment: How did you arrive at the unrolled loop? Did you profile and it was faster? Have you profiled memcpying a whole row at a time?

Comment: Assuming `bytes == 4`: `xend = xoffset + width*bytes; for (x = xoffset; x < xend; x += bytes)` spares the multiplication within the loop.

Answer (score 2):

It's not unlikely that the compiler optimises in this direction anyway, but we can spare some multiplications by adding the appropriate ranges instead of just incrementing, and we can spare some additions by setting the initial start point outside the loop; additionally, using pointer arithmetic, we need only half of additions (x[y] is equivalent to *(x + y)!):

```
byte* srcdata = (byte*)compatablePixels;
// moving out of loop as many operations as possible:
byte* dstdata = (byte*)lockedRectSubImg.pBits
              + lockedRectSubImg.Pitch * yoffset + xoffset;

byte* end = dstdata + height * lockedRectSubImg.Pitch;
int xrange = width * bytes;
int step = lockedRectSubImg.Pitch - width * bytes;
// += step: avoid multiplications inside loop!
for (; dstdata < end; dstdata += step)
{
    for (x = xrange; x != 0; x--)
    // on some platforms, comparing against 0 is faster; at least, it is never slower...
    {
        dstdata++ = srcdata++;
    }
}
```

Using memcpy:

```
byte* end = dstdata + height * lockedRectSubImg.Pitch;
int xrange = width * bytes;
for (; dstdata < end; dstdata += lockedRectSubImg.Pitch, srcdata += xrange)
{
    memcpy(dstdata, srcdata, xrange);
}
```

Untested code, though, if you find a bug, find a frog to feed it to as well...